# what is "1 in array[]" mean in Julia?

Tags: python, python-3.x, julia

I'm in a situation where I have to rewrite some Julia code into Python code and I cannot reproduce this line.

```
if 1 in array1[array2] || 1 in array1[array3]
```

In my understanding, this line comparing arrays `array1` to `array2` and `array1` to `array3`, to see if the index `array2` of `array1` is `1` or the index `array3` of `array1` is `1`.

So, I reproduced this code into python code with my understand,

```
for i, j in zip(array2, array3):
    if array1[i] == 1 or array1[j] == 1:
```

But this code didn't work like an above code and I got a ValueError like below:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I'm not sure if this is my misunderstanding of the Julia's line or my Python code is wrong.

Could someone tell me what is wrong?

[edit]:
Here is Julia code of this problem. here I am using [karate club network](http://networkrepository.com/soc-karate.php) as an input matrix
dir  = "to/your/path"
ln = "soc-karate.mtx"

```
mtx = MatrixMarketRead(string(dir,strip(ln)));
A = mtx - spdiagm(diag(mtx))
n = size(A,1);
A = speye(n) - A * spdiagm(1./vec(sum(A,1)));
println(A)
function findDegrees(Ac::SparseMatrixCSC)
  degrees = zeros(Int,length(Ac.colptr)-1)
    for i = 1:length(degrees)
      degrees[i] = Ac.colptr[i+1]-Ac.colptr[i]-1
    end
  return degrees
end

function lowDegreeNodes(A::SparseMatrixCSC,At::SparseMatrixCSC,d::Int64,dout::Vector,din::Vector)
  # 1: find low degree nodes
  n = size(A,1)
  U = collect(dout.==1)
  println(U)
  V = collect(din.==1)
  Z = min((dout+din) .>= 1 , (dout+din) .<= 8 )
  # 2:  visited = 0  ==> NotVisited
  #             = 1  ==> FNode
  #             = 2  ==> NotEliminated
  visited = zeros(length(U))
  
  for u = 1:n
    if Z[u]
      if visited[u] == 0
        Au = A.rowval[ A.colptr[u]:A.colptr[u+1]-1 ]
        Av = At.rowval[ At.colptr[u]:At.colptr[u+1]-1 ]
        if 1 in visited[Au] || 1 in visited[Av]
          visited[u] = 2
        else
          visited[Au] = 2
          visited[u] = 1
        end
      end
    end

    if V[u]
      if visited[u] == 0
        Au = A.rowval[ A.colptr[u]:A.colptr[u+1]-1 ]
        Av = At.rowval[ At.colptr[u]:At.colptr[u+1]-1 ]
        if 1 in visited[Au] || 1 in visited[Av]
          visited[u] = 2
        else
          visited[Av] = 2
          visited[u] = 1
        end
      end
    end

    if U[u]
      if visited[u] == 0
                Au = A.rowval[ A.colptr[u]:A.colptr[u+1]-1 ]

        Av = At.rowval[ At.colptr[u]:At.colptr[u+1]-1 ]
        if 1 in visited[Au] || 1 in visited[Av]
          visited[u] = 2
        else
          visited[Av] = 2
          visited[u] = 1
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return visited .== 1
end
dout = findDegrees(A)
din = findDegrees(A')
z = lowDegreeNodes(A, A', 3, dout, din)
```

Comment: looks like your arrays are multidimensional... please provide a [mre].

Comment: An alternative to converting would by calling Julia from Python with pyJulia (or vice versa with PyCall).

In general, Julia is a much more performant language, therefore converting your code to Python may be disadvantageous in the long run.

Comment: @lungben this Julia code is written in Julia 0.5.2. will it works fine?

Comment: You have to try it out. Julia 0.5 is quite old and there have been breaking changes up to Julia 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> if 1 in array1[array2] || 1 in array1[array3]
> ```
>
> In my understanding, this line comparing arrays array1 to array2 and array1 to array3, to see if the index array2 of array1 is 1 or the index array3 of array1 is 1.

I don't think that's correct. I think this line tests if `1` is in the values of `array1` at indices `array2` or indices `array3`. Let me make a MWE:

```
julia> array2 = [2, 3]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3

julia> array3 = [4, 5]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 4
 5

julia> array1 = [1, 9, 1, 2, 3]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 9
 1
 2
 3

julia> 1 in array1[array2] || 1 in array1[array3]
true

julia> array1 = [1, 9, 4, 2, 3] # now only at the 1st position is there a 1
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 9
 4
 2
 3

julia> 1 in array1[array2] || 1 in array1[array3]
false
```

Comment: Actually, the Julia syntax is nearly the same as in Python here, you just need to replace || by or.

Comment: Python contrary to Julia is using `0`-based indexing so most likely you will need to substract 1 from array2 and array3

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your understanding of this line is correct:</strike>

*Edit: Ok, after reading your description again, I am not sure the understanding is correct, but hopefully this explanation will clarify it.*

```
if 1 in array1[array2] || 1 in array1[array3]
```

You choose the elements in `array1` at indexes given by `array2` and `array3` and check if any of these elements is a `1`

So if your `array1` is `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `array2` is `[1, 3, 4]`, `array1[array2]` would be `[0, 2, 3]` (remember, arrays are indexed by 1 in Julia!) and thus `1 in array1[array2]` would evlauate to `false`

You can achieve something similar with `numpy` but remember that since python indexes by 0, you have to subtract 1 from the indexes if you want the code stay equivalent for same input data:

```
array1 = np.array([...]) # Fill your arrays with the data
array2 = np.array([...])
array3 = np.array([...])


if 1 in array1[array2 - 1] or 1 in array1[array3 - 1]:
    # Rest of code
```

The syntax `1 in <array>` is same as in Julia, it evaluates to `True` if the value `1` is contained in `<array>`

Answer (score 0):

If these are regular python lists (and built assuming 0 indexed arrays) you could do

```
array1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3]
array2 = [0,2]
array3 = [3,5]

print(any(array1[i]==1 for i in array2), any(array1[i]==1 for i in array3))

if any(array1[i]==1 for i in array2) or any(array1[i]==1 for i in array3):
    print("Yes")
```

This would fail if indicies in the second two arrays overflow the first. In that case you could scrub them first.

```
array2 = [i for i in array2 if i < len(array1)]
array3 = [i for i in array3 if i < len(array1)]
```

Comment: I ran `print(any(array1[i] == 1 for I in array2))` and got an error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index` despite `array2` has an int elements in it. `array2` has `[array([ 7, 12], dtype=int32)]` for your information.

Comment: I am showing how this would work with lists. Does this exact code work for you? You haven't told us what types these arrays are. Can you post a fully running example? Python extension modules like numpy and pandas will work differently than a vanilla list of ints. I've shown you how to do it with these basic types.